# Python: Remove Sublists from List if Same Including/Not Including Order

Tags: python, list, sublist

Is there a way to remove duplicate sublists from a list of lists, even if they are not the same ordering?

So could I do something like make:

```
x = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[2,1],[7,8]]
```

into

```
x = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]]
```

Is there an itertools function or something with a for loop?

Thanks!

Comment: Will you ever have to distinguish `[1,1,2]` from `[1,2,1]`?  And do you need to preserve the initial order of the sublists?

Comment: Also, is the order of the returned list significant?

Comment: @DSM yes, the length of the sublists may increase. And no, the order is not important.

Comment: @DSM, but the order within the sublists is important, so [7,8] is not the same as [8,7].

Comment: @DSM Yes, that is what I mean. If for a sublist there is a matching one elsewhere in the list, then one, preferably the second, should be removed. But, for a sublist which does not have a duplicate, it should remain the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this will preserve the order of list and sublists, with possible duplicates in sublists:

```
y, s = [], set()
for t in x:
    w = tuple(sorted(t))
    if not w in s:
        y.append(t)
        s.add(w)
```

if

```
x = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[2,1,1],[2,1],[7,8],[4,3],[1,2,1]]
```

then `y` will be:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [2, 1, 1], [7, 8]]
```

Comment: +1: This preserves as much original information as possible (unlike my OrderedDict approach), and seems to satisfy the OP's desiderata.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `frozenset`:

```
>>> def remove_dups(L):
        return map(list, frozenset(map(frozenset, L)))

>>> x = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[2,1],[7,8]]
>>> remove_dups(x)
[[5, 6], [1, 2], [8, 7], [3, 4]]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
a=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[2,1],[7,8]]
y=[]
for i in a:
        if sorted(i) not in y:
                y.append(i)
print y
```

output is

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]
```