# Remove duplicate sublists from a list

Tags: python, list, duplicates

If I have a list like this one:

```
mylist = [[1,2,3], ['a', 'c'], [3,4,5],[1,2], [3,4,5], ['a', 'c'], [3,4,5], [1,2]]
```

What is best way to remove duplicate sub-lists?

Now I use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20462808/4599833):

```
y, s = [ ], set( )
for t in mylist:
    w = tuple( sorted( t ) )
    if not w in s:
        y.append( t )
        s.add( w )
```

It works, but I wonder if there is better way? Something more python-like?

Comment: I don't want to change the order.

Comment: Then icodez is the answer you should use, is `[1,2]` a dupe of `[2,1]`?

Comment: your accepted answer does not keep the order, sets don't have any order

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you remove duplicates from a list in Python whilst preserving order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-in-python-whilst-preserving-order)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Convert the elements to a tuple*, then convert it the whole thing to a set, then convert everything back to a list:

```
m = [[1,2,3], ['a', 'c'], [3,4,5],[1,2], [3,4,5], ['a', 'c'], [3,4,5], [1,2]]

print [list(i) for i in set(map(tuple, m))]
```

*we are converting to tuples because lists are non-hashable (and therefore we cannot use set on them

Comment: Thank you. Works as I wanted.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`OrderedDict.fromkeys`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) to filter duplicates out of the list while still preserving order:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> mylist = [[1,2,3], ['a', 'c'], [3,4,5],[1,2], [3,4,5], ['a', 'c'], [3,4,5], [1,2]]
>>> map(list, OrderedDict.fromkeys(map(tuple, mylist)))
[[1, 2, 3], ['a', 'c'], [3, 4, 5], [1, 2]]
>>>
```

The `map(tuple, mylist)` is necessary because dictionary keys must be hashable (lists are not since you can add/remove items from them).

Answer (score 5):

Well, since `set`s inherently dedupe things, your first instinct might be to do `set(mylist)`. However, that doesn't quite work:

```
In [1]: mylist = [[1,2,3], ['a', 'c'], [3,4,5],[1,2], [3,4,5], ['a', 'c'], [3,4,5], [1,2]]

In [2]: set(mylist)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-b352bcae5975> in <module>()
----> 1 set(mylist)

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

This is because `set`s only work on `iterable`s of hashable elements (and since `list`s are mutable, they are not hashable).

Instead, you can do this simply for the price of converting your sublists to subtuples:

```
In [3]: set([tuple(x) for x in mylist])
Out[3]: {(1, 2), (1, 2, 3), (3, 4, 5), ('a', 'c')}
```

Or, if you really need a list of lists again:

```
In [4]: [list(x) for x in set([tuple(x) for x in mylist])]
Out[4]: [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], ['a', 'c'], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvote, since it demonstrably solves OP's problem as stated?

Comment: I upvoted you guys to cancel out the downvote. Seriously what was that bout?

Answer (score 4):

Because you have `sorted(t)` in your question, I assume you consider `[1,2]` to be a duplicate of `[2,1]`

If this is true, I'd use frozenset for the inside lists (which are hashable) and will not care about the ordering of the sublists.

So something like:

```
set(frozenset(sublist) for sublist in mylist)
```

Comment: The code was taken from another question, the sort is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to sort, the sort in the code you copied is sorting for a different reason:

```
seen,out = set(), []

for ele in mylist:
    tp = tuple(ele)
    if tp not in seen:
        out.append(ele)
    seen.add(tp)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well this will work for your case:

```
mylist2 = set(map(tuple, mylist))
print(mylist2) # ('a', 'c'), (3, 4, 5), (1, 2), (1, 2, 3)}
```

This works, because it changes your sublists to tuples, which in your case are hashable. So set can take them and make a unique.

And in case you really want the output to be a list of lists, you can do this:

```
print(list(map(list,mylist2))) # [['a', 'c'], [3, 4, 5], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: I upvoted you guys to cancel out the downvote. Seriously what was that bout?

Comment: @Secret Thx. Some ppl seem to download for no apparent reason.

Comment: Probably because the result you get is a set of tuples instead of a list of lists

Comment: The OPs code also makes a set of tuples. So I guess its not a problem for the OP.

Comment: The OP makes tuples to add to the set not the list

Answer (score 1):

If order and structure (list of lists) don't matter, you can use

```
set(map(tuple, my_list))
```

if they do matter, you can use a list comprehension

```
[e for i,e in enumerate(my_list) if e not in my_list[:i]]
```

which keeps only the first duplicate of every element, thus keeping only one of each. It is marginally slower

```
In [16]: timeit.timeit('[e for i,e in enumerate(my_list) if e not in my_list[:i]]', setup="my_list = [[1,2,3], ['a', 'c'], [3,4,5],[1,2], [3,4,5], ['a', 'c'], [3,4,5], [1,2]]")
Out[16]: 1.9146944019994407

In [17]: timeit.timeit('set(map(tuple, my_list))', setup="my_list = [[1,2,3], ['a', 'c'], [3,4,5],[1,2], [3,4,5], ['a', 'c'], [3,4,5], [1,2]]")
Out[17]: 1.3857673469974543
```

but if you care about speed you should probably try a loopey approach.