# How to update loop variable with range function?

Tags: python, list

I want to remove duplicates from a list. I know it can be done easily with `list(dict.fromkeys(my list))`, but I want to do it by iterating through the list. When I am removing a duplicate number from the list, the loop variable `j` causes an `Index error : list index out of range` later in subsequent iterations, even though I am changing the range input. I am wondering how to change loop variable inside loop ?

```
def rem_duplicate(seq):
    for i in range(len(seq)):
        num = seq[i]
        count = 0
        length = len(seq)
        for j in range(length):
            if seq[j] == num:
                count += 1
                if count > 1:
                    del seq[j]
                    length=length-1
    return seq

my_list = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 3, 4, 1, 5, 2, 5, 7, 9]

print(rem_duplicate(my_list))
```

Comment: Especially this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42773232/895932 that uses a while loop.

Comment: you could directly use set(my_list) or for iteration you could use while loop instead

Comment: Your changing of `length` variable inside the `for` loop does nothing. The loop has already been initialised with the original value of length and the value won't be updated.

Comment: also mutating a list like this while iterating through it is a nightmare, the moment you delete an element your loop counter becomes incorrect, a better way is to filter out the elements you don't want and to accumulate in another list using a list comprehension as linked to above.

Comment: List comprehension cannot be used to delete duplicates since it cannot access other elements, so I suggested an answer in that duplicate target question that uses a while loop, which is applicable in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> range(len(seq))

Will return an inmutable sequence, that will not be affected by add / del operations over the original list.
Take a look to the previous answers to the same question (using a while):  [Python: remove duplicate items from a list while iterating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43529348/python-remove-duplicate-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

Answer (score 2):

When you enter the inner loop, the `range()` function is called with current value of length, say, 3. So, your loop would look like `for j in [1, 2, 3]` and changing `length` won't affect changing the mentioned list.

To achieve what you want, and also when mutating the size of the list you're iterating on, it's always better to use a `while` loop:

```py
j = 0
while j < length:
  if seq[j] == num:
    count += 1
    if count > 1:
      del seq[j]
      length=length-1
  j += 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked although I had to change the outer loop also to while loop. range returning immutable sequence makes sense.