# Remove duplicate items in an array with not same-ordered inside elements

Tags: python, list

Our example list:

```py
(
    [(), (2, 0)], 
    [(2,), (0,)], 
    [(), (0, 2)], 
    [(0,), (2,)]
)
```

I want to be able to remove duplicates in the list, and by this I mean same inside elements.

This means the elements `[(2,), (0,)]` and `[(0,), (2,)]`  in the list are same. So in summary, i want to remove different order inside elements. Note that this example is of `2` inside elements but I want it for any number. I want to keep whatever comes first as long as they are not both (or a many duplicates we have) there.

I thought about sorting the inner elements, converting to str them checking for duplicates, but I am not sure if this is the way and I don't know how to make it

For example an element of `[(),(2,0),(1,)]` is the same as `[(),(1,),(2,0)]`.

Comment: Is your list a list of `str` types, or of `list` types? Not sure if a typo by you, or intentional.

Comment: I edited the list to remove the str of elements. The outer one is list

Comment: The fact that you have 3 levels of list nesting makes this a bit trickier.  Is `[(), (0,2), (1,)]` the same as `[(), (2,0),(1,)]`?

Comment: it is important the order of elements(lists) after removing the duplicates?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Remove Sublists from List if Same Including/Not Including Order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20462664/python-remove-sublists-from-list-if-same-including-not-including-order)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use [fozensets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset):

```
l = (
    [(), (2, 0)], 
    [(2,), (0,)], 
    [(), (0, 2)], 
    [(0,), (2,)]
)


r = set()

result = tuple()
for e in l:
    f = frozenset(e)
    if f not in r:
        result += (e,)
        r.add(f)
result
```

output:

```
([(), (2, 0)], [(2,), (0,)], [(), (0, 2)]
```

if the order of the lists is not important you can use:

```
tuple(list(e) for e in {frozenset(e) for e in l})
```

output:

```
([(), (0, 2)], [(2,), (0,)], [(2, 0), ()])
```

Comment: @Todd no, the elements from the tuples inside of the lists are not allowed to change the order, only the tuples inside lists are allowed to change the order

Comment: You do the same using `sorted(e)` and `result` as a list. But with `frozenset` it's little bit faster. Good answer by the way.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this, is to sort the values in the list and remove check if the nth element exists in the next part of the list

```py
from itertools import compress

lst = (
    [(), (2, 0)], 
    [(2,), (0,)], 
    [(), (0, 2)], 
    [(0,), (2,)]
)

_ = list(map(lambda x: x.sort(), lst))
list(compress(lst, [x not in lst[i+1:] for i, x in enumerate(lst)]))
```